# Prove the following statement for prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

> Show that it is not possible for $k>3$ prime numbers, each greater than $k$, to be in arithmetic progression with common difference less than or equal to $k+1$.

$p$>$k$ and $p,p+d,...,p+(k-1)d$ are k prime numbers.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the question?

Comment: @amWhy I'm happy to delete post-edit, but I don't follow your comment.  It is entirely possible for there to exist $2$ primes in arithmetic progression, each $>2$, with common difference $\le 3$.  Those are indeed called twin primes.

Comment: @ErickWong: It is often useful to violate the hypotheses, find a counterexample, and think about how the hypotheses rule it out.   Your example of twin primes is a good one in this spirit.  Another is $\{3,5,7\}$

Answer (score 1):

When I see a problem like this I first try small $k$.  The smallest $k$ allowed is $4$.  In that case, one of the numbers in the progression will be even unless the difference is $2$, when one will be a multiple of $3$.  For larger $k$ the difference must be even so all the numbers can be odd.  Similarly, the difference must be a multiple of $3$ so all the numbers can have a remainder on division by $3$.  Now the difference is a multiple of $6$, so $k \ge 5$.  Keep on this way until the product of the primes gets so large that you can use Bertrand's postulate to show that two must have a common factor so the higher cannot be prime.